# Multiple level ordering

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting

I have a table with some records with fields like name, rating etc.

I first want to sort based on rating limiting results to 20 and then on this resultset want to further apply sort based on name.

I know to sort we need to use the query like

```
Select * from table order by rating Desc limit 20
```

but on this resultset how to apply another level of ordering? How can I combine these two sorts in one sqlite statement?

Answer (score 152):

You could use e.g. `ORDER BY rating DESC, name ASC` to sort by rating and then, if the ratings are equal, by name.

Comment: in SQL `ASC` is default value so it can be `ORDER BY rating DESC, name`

Comment: @VasileDoe: Yes you can, and I think it's very ugly to do so if you have anything that's not ASC within the same statement.

Comment: But to have the 20 best sorted by name (what the question was) you have to use, though ugly, @JuanBoca's suggestion

Comment: For completeness:
`Select * from table ORDER BY rating DESC, name ASC`

Answer (score 25):

This query should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 20) ORDER BY name
```